# How to create a tri-stage flip-slider in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, flip

I need to to create a tri-stage flip-slider in jQuery Mobile. Is there any known solution? Or maybe is there a way to mod the jQuery Mobile flip toggle switch to work as a tri-stage slider? This would be the starting point:

```
<div class="containing-element">
    <label for="triflip">Multi Flip Selector</label>
    <select name="triflip" id="triflip" data-role="slider">
    <option value="0">Yes</option>
    <option value="1">No</option>
    <option value="2">Maybe</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/headkit/5aaB8/1/).

Comment: Could you use the existing jQM slider like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5aaB8/2/

Comment: or build your own gadget like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/m48dT/112/

Comment: @ezanker nice examples, thanx! yes, I thought about using the slider solution , but I wanted the look and feel of the flip selector. but I like your second link!

Comment: i've updated that one with the ability to get the value: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/m48dT/114/

Comment: @ezanker great example!